# What are the pros and cons of sw-toolbox's cacheFirst handler versus the fastest handler?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've read [sw-toolbox API documentation](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/sw-toolbox/api.html) and some other articles on the subject.

I get the impression that if I use *toolbox.fastest*, I won't have to manage my caches as much because the cache is updated when the network requests come back.  I am concerned that the inherent network requests are going to be a bottleneck, though.  Is that the case?

Are there any other things I should consider when evaluating these two handlers?

Answer (score 2):

> CacheFirst Strategy which results in a copy of any cached content
>   being returned without consulting the network.

`Pros`:

- If you're building offline-first, this is how you'll handle the majority of requests.
- CacheFirst improves and speeds up browsing. Once you've downloaded an asset, it lives (for a time) on your machine. Retrieving files from your hard drive will always be faster than retrieving them from a remote server, no matter how fast your Internet connection.
- Mobile devices are frequently limited by bandwidth. The less a user has to download of a website, the better for them.

`Cons`:

- No major pitfall apart from you need to find a way out to purge or clear [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).

> Fastest Strategy, request the resource from both the cache and the
>   network in parallel. Respond with whichever returns first.

`Pros`:

- Whenever the network request completes the cache is updated, so future cache reads will always be up-to-date.
- Ideal for small assets where you're chasing performance on devices with slow disk access. As sometimes on older hard drives, or machine running anti-viruses, Getting resources from the network can be quicker than going to disk.

`Cons`:

- Going to the network even when the user has the content on their device can be a waste of data specially on low latency networks.
- Bandwidth Overage since it makes HTTP network request to remote server every time the page reloads. Some mobile data plans also have bandwidth caps or charges.

References:- [offline-cookbook](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/)   [sw-toolbox](https://googlechrome.github.io/sw-toolbox/docs/master/tutorial-api)